# Incorrect question edit attribution

Tags: support, questions, edits, attribution

I have recently edited the title of the following question on SO (Revision 2):

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4767648/revisions

In the edit history for revision 2 there is also an edit to the question contents and it is attributed to me. I am almost certain that I did not make that edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the OP saved an edit to the question after you started editing. Since it was in the five minute grace period it doesn't show up as a separate revision.

Then when you saved your edit (with the old unchanged body) the new edit by the OP got overwritten by your older version of the question body. So the question body changed when you saved your revision and the diff reflects that.

This happens from time to time since there is no detection of edit collisions.

Comment: Even then, @chibacity, your edit was saved within 3.5 minutes after the question was asked. Just in case you don't know: that shortens the grace period for the original author. (In fact, the 3rd revision was posted within 5 minutes after posting the question too, so probably the author tried to fine tune twice within those 5 minutes.)